# R: cannot run specific cmd code that converts .xls to .xlsx

Tags: r, excel, cmd

Long time reader, first time writter...

Im writting some R code that shall take some data input from other sources.
 One place can only give data as a .xls format. While there is good excel capabilities in R, this .xls file cannot be read from R. But if i convert it to .xlsx R handels it fine. So im gonna convert it.

In a direct cmd input, i cann convert it by doing as below:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/excelcnv.exe" -oice "C:/Users/my_name/OneDrive - work/Documents/Dashboard code/New Code/work_STD_TEMPLATE.xls" "C:/Users/my_name/OneDrive - work/Documents/Dashboard code/New Code/work_STD_TEMPLATE2.xlsx"
```

But I wish to automate the code, so implementing this would be best. See below for the version i can compile and run.

R-code:

```
args = c("C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/excelcnv.exe" , 
         '-oice' , "C:/Users/my_name/OneDrive - work/Documents/Dashboard code/New Code/work_STD_TEMPLATE.xls" , "C:/Users/my_name/OneDrive - work/Documents/Dashboard code/New Code/work_STD_TEMPLATE2.xlsx");
system2(args)
```

But while it runs it stalls the system and finally promts a pop-upbox that tells me:

excelcnv.exe - Application Error
The application was unable to start correctly (0x0000142).

I need big brain person for this. Thanks in advance

Found answer last night:

```
 args = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\excelcnv.exe\" -oice \"C:\\Users\\my_name\\OneDrive - work\\Documents\\Dashboard code\\New Code\\work_STD_TEMPLATE.xls\" \"C:\\Users\\my_name\\OneDrive - work\\Documents\\Dashboard code\\New Code\\work_STD_TEMPLATE2.xlsx\""
   system("cmd.exe" , input = args)
```

I needed to escape charterer the escape characters... so \ had to be \ and " had to be \"

Comment: Have you experimented with the R package [xlsx](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.1)?

Comment: Or readxl - https://readxl.tidyverse.org?

Comment: Yes for both. Normal excel wont open the file either but will only touch it if converted to .xlsx
(The data extract is from a legacy system anno 1997, and when open the formatting is pure cancer. Multi coloured and different fonts. But i need the data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer last night:

```
 args = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\excelcnv.exe\" -oice \"C:\\Users\\my_name\\OneDrive - work\\Documents\\Dashboard code\\New Code\\work_STD_TEMPLATE.xls\" \"C:\\Users\\my_name\\OneDrive - work\\Documents\\Dashboard code\\New Code\\work_STD_TEMPLATE2.xlsx\""
   system("cmd.exe" , input = args)
```

I needed to escape charterer the escape characters... so \ had to be \ and " had to be \"

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a XLS file to a XLSX file with the following function using the RDCOMClient R package :

```
convert_XLS_File_To_XLSX <- function(path_XLS_File, path_XLSX_File)
{
  xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  xlApp[['Visible']] <- FALSE
  xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_XLS_File)
  xlWbk$SaveAs(path_XLSX_File, 51)
  xlWbk$Close()
  xlApp$Quit()
}

library(RDCOMClient)
convert_XLS_File_To_XLSX(path_XLS_File, path_XLSX_File)
```

This is an interesting alternative from my point of view.